# Kafka broker not attempting to restart after session timeout

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've **3 brokers** containers and **1 zookeeper** container running in a docker stack, both zookeeper container and brokers **containers keeps stopping after some days (less than a week) running in an idle state.**

*This is one of the brokers logs where i see an error, but i can not identify how to handle it*

```
[2022-07-13 02:22:30,109] INFO [UnifiedLog partition=messages-processed-0, dir=/bitnami/kafka/data] Truncating to 6 has no effect as the largest offset in the log is 5 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog)
[2022-07-13 02:23:33,766] INFO [Controller id=1] Newly added brokers: , deleted brokers: 2, bounced brokers: , all live brokers: 1,3 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2022-07-13 02:23:33,766] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Shutting down (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2022-07-13 02:23:33,853] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Stopped (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2022-07-13 02:23:33,853] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=1] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2022-07-13 02:23:34,226] INFO [Controller id=1] Broker failure callback for 2 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2022-07-13 02:23:34,227] INFO [Controller id=1 epoch=3] Sending UpdateMetadata request to brokers Set() for 0 partitions (state.change.logger)
[2022-07-13 02:23:36,414] ERROR [Controller id=1 epoch=3] Controller 1 epoch 3 failed to change state for partition __consumer_offsets-30 from OfflinePartition to OnlinePartition (state.change.logger)
kafka.common.StateChangeFailedException: Failed to elect leader for partition __consumer_offsets-30 under strategy OfflinePartitionLeaderElectionStrategy(false)
    at kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine.$anonfun$doElectLeaderForPartitions$7(PartitionStateMachine.scala:424)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine.doElectLeaderForPartitions(PartitionStateMachine.scala:421)
    at kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartitions(PartitionStateMachine.scala:332)
    at kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine.doHandleStateChanges(PartitionStateMachine.scala:238)
    at kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine.handleStateChanges(PartitionStateMachine.scala:158)
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlineStateChangeForPartitions(PartitionStateMachine.scala:74)
    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:59)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onReplicasBecomeOffline(KafkaController.scala:627)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onBrokerFailure(KafkaController.scala:597)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.processBrokerChange(KafkaController.scala:1621)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.process(KafkaController.scala:2495)
    at kafka.controller.QueuedEvent.process(ControllerEventManager.scala:52)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread.process$1(ControllerEventManager.scala:130)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread.$anonfun$doWork$1(ControllerEventManager.scala:133)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:31)
    at kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread.doWork(ControllerEventManager.scala:133)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

*This is a part of the zookeeper log at the same time*

```
2022-07-13 02:14:45,002 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@632] - Expiring session 0x10000fba7760000, timeout of 18000ms exceeded
2022-07-13 02:15:13,001 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@632] - Expiring session 0x10000fba7760007, timeout of 18000ms exceeded
2022-07-13 02:15:29,832 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-1:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1087] - Invalid session 0x10000fba7760006 for client /172.18.0.5:55356, probably expired
2022-07-13 02:15:42,419 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-1:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1087] - Invalid session 0x10000fba7760000 for client /172.18.0.4:59474, probably expired
2022-07-13 02:15:52,350 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-2:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1087] - Invalid session 0x10000fba7760007 for client /172.18.0.6:34406, probably expired
2022-07-13 02:16:49,001 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@632] - Expiring session 0x10000fba776000b, timeout of 18000ms exceeded
2022-07-13 02:17:12,434 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-2:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1087] - Invalid session 0x10000fba776000b for client /172.18.0.5:56264, probably expired
2022-07-13 02:19:17,067 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-1:o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn@371] - Unexpected exception
org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client, it probably closed the socket: address = /172.18.0.4:60150, session = 0x10000fba776000d
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.handleFailedRead(NIOServerCnxn.java:170)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:333)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:508)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-07-13 02:23:29,002 [myid:] - INFO  [SessionTracker:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@632] - Expiring session 0x10000fba776000e, timeout of 18000ms exceeded
2022-07-13 02:24:05,059 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOWorkerThread-1:o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer@1087] - Invalid session 0x10000fba776000e for client /172.18.0.5:32886, probably expired
2022-07-13 03:48:55,209 [myid:] - WARN  [NIOWorkerThread-2:o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn@371] - Unexpected exception
org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client, it probably closed the socket: address = /172.18.0.4:33508, session = 0x10000fba776000d
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.handleFailedRead(NIOServerCnxn.java:170)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:333)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:508)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I've seen that a maxSessionTimeout of 40000ms is set on my zoo.cfg (zookeeper side) and a timeout of 18000ms is set on the server.properties at broker side, should i increment one of those?

**kafka-topic --describe ** about one of the topics that fell https://prnt.sc/r3hU5wv3jK-h

[Image used for the broker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/)

Comment: Ideally, you dont run 3 brokers on one Docker host. You're wasting disk cycles for each replica

Comment: @OneCricketeer Any source to read more about this waste that you are mentioning? i don't fully understand the concept

Comment: You have one host. It has one disk. Kafka replicas data across brokers. For every extra broker you add, you are forcing extra writes to your disk where there really doesn't need to be any replication because its main purpose is _fault tolerance_, not performance. In other words, one broker will (probably) work faster on one host rather than 3 due to less disk I/O

Comment: In any case, do you frequently get this error? What docker image are you using? What are your full broker/ZK configs? Can you reproduce it and then run `kafka-topics --describe` for the topics mentioned in the logs?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I appreciate the detailed information, i've just updated the post with the topic description and a link to the image that i'm using (dockerhub).

About the frequency, it varies, in example, since the restart after this post, 2 brokers keep working (almost 3 weeks) but one fell 4 days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your uploaded image, it appears `brokerId=1` has crashed on its own. And probably not related to the logs you've shown.

The logs that you did show ("Failed to elect leader") are happening  on the **other** brokers because `ReplicationFactor: 1` on `__consumer_offsets`. Thus why you have `Leader: None, Replicas: 1`. In a healthy Kafka cluster, no partition leaders should be none.

[This can be fixed for an existing Kafka cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52642924/2308683) using `kafka-reassign-partitions`, but since you are using Docker, the best way to fix this would be to first clear all the data, stop the containers, then add your missing `KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3` environment variable and restart them all.

Or as mentioned in the comments, don't use 3 brokers on a single host. And if you are using a single host, timeouts aren't really relevant because all network requests are local.

Comment: Thanks! 2 question remaining. At first, which could be the reason or do you know how to debug the crash of brokerId=1 on its own?. Then, what documentation should i read to know the reference for those variables such as KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR?

Comment: 1) No idea. `docker logs` and pipe it to less, then search for ERROR or Exception. 2) See "Configuration" section in the DockerHub repo

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following.

```
docker volume rm sentry-kafka
docker volume rm sentry-zookeeper
docker volume rm sentry_onpremise_sentry-kafka-log
docker volume rm sentry_onpremise_sentry-zookeeper-log


./install.sh // to create Kafka partitions
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using docker volumes or that these names match theirs?

Comment: Such as @OneCricketeer mentioned, currently i'm not using docker volumes

Comment: @AtarC5 But are you using docker volume mounts? If not, the whole Docker container is ephemeral and the data is not expected to be persisted. And I personally do not consider it best practice to expect any Docker container to have uptime beyond a few days without any restarts, especially for a local environment.